# Django listview to list only if it receives a true value

Tags: python, django

I'm developing an application that generates requests (in the context of city hall, not web requests). I'm using Django 1.11.

In my shopping area I have a view using `get_context_data` to get the objects of my requests and list them. My problem is that there are several sectors and the request will only be listed in the next sector if the previous one approves.

In my `models.py` I have the class Request `(Solicitacao)` and the class SecretaryApproval `(SecretarioAprovacao)` that is related to my request.

What I need to do is, before displaying the data, to check all the requests and only list those assigned to the user and also containt `True` in the field `secretario_aprovacao`

**models.py**

```
class SecretarioAprovacao(models.Model):
    secretario_relacionamento = models.ForeignKey(Solicitacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secretario_aprovacao_CHOICES = (
        (True, 'Sim'),
        (False, 'Não')
    )
    secretario_aprovacao = models.BooleanField("Aprovar Solicitação?",
        choices = secretario_aprovacao_CHOICES,
        default = True,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Secretario Aprovação"
        verbose_name_plural = "Secretario Aprovações"
```

**view.py**

```
class Compraslist(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Solicitacao
    template_name = 'compraslist.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Compraslist, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['solicitacoes'] = Solicitacao.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it:

```
approved_request_ids = SecretarioAprovacao.objects.filter(secretario_aprovacao=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
context['solicitacoes'] = Solicitacao.objects.filter(id__in=approved_request_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your `Solicitacao` model, so I cannot give a full answer. I assume there is a field like `solicitacao_user` that indicates the owner or creator of the request.

If I understand your question correctly, you could try something like this. It shows all requests that belong to the currently logged in user and that also have at least one approval with `True`.

```
# views.py
class Compraslist(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    # ... more code ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        approved_pk_set = set(
            e.pk for e in SecretarioAprovacao.objects.filter(secretario_aprovacao=True))
        ctx['solicitacoes'] = Solicitacao.objects.filter(pk__in=approved_pk_set, solicitacao_user=self.request.user)
        return ctx
```